# Efficiently selecting from many-to-many relation in H2

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, h2

I'm using H2, and I have a database of books (table Entries) and authors (table Persons), connected through a many-to-many relationship, itself stored in a table Authorship. 
The database is fairly large (900'000+ persons and 2.5M+ books).

I'm  trying to efficiently select the list of all books authored by at least one author whose name matches a pattern (LIKE '%pattern%'). The trick here is that the pattern should severly restrict the number of matching authors, and each author has a reasonably small number of associated books.

I tried two queries:

```
SELECT p.*, e.title FROM (SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE name LIKE '%pattern%')  AS p
  INNER JOIN Authorship AS au ON au.authorId = p.id
  INNER JOIN Entries AS e ON e.id = au.entryId;
```

and:

```
SELECT p.*, e.title FROM Persons AS p
  INNER JOIN Authorship AS au ON au.authorId = p.id
  INNER JOIN Entries AS e ON e.id = au.entryId
WHERE p.name like '%pattern%';
```

I expected the first one to be much faster, as I'm joining a much smaller (sub)table of authors, however they both take as long. So long in fact that I can manually decompose the query into three selects and find the result I want faster.

When I try to EXPLAIN the queries, I observe that indeed they are very similar (a full join on the tables and only then a WHERE clause), so my question is: how can I achieve a fast select, that relies on the fact that the filter on authors should result in a much smaller join with the other two tables?

Note that I tried the same queries with MySQL and got results in line with what I expected (selecting first is much faster).

Thank you.

Comment: Why that SUBSELECT in the first JOIN? Why not simply `INNER JOIN Authorship AS au ON ... `?

Comment: You're right, I made the change. The queries translate to the same thing (according to EXPLAIN at least) but are now simpler, thanks.

Comment: What is the result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...` for those queries?

Comment: I put the results for the three queries (two from the original post and the one from my answer) in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Z04BRuDa). Sorry about the index names, they were automatically generated. Incidentally, my database contains 726 entries authored by someone named Mueller :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is something that finally worked for me.

Instead of running the query:

```
SELECT p.*, e.title FROM (SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE name LIKE '%pattern%') AS p
  INNER JOIN Authorship AS au ON au.authorId = p.id
  INNER JOIN Entries AS e ON e.id = au.entryId;
```

...I ran:

```
SELECT title FROM Entries e WHERE id IN (
  SELECT entryId FROM Authorship WHERE authorId IN (
    SELECT id FROM Persons WHERE name LIKE '%pattern%'
  )
)
```

It's not *exactly* the same query, because now I don't get the author id as a column in the result, but that does what I wanted: take advantage of the fact that the pattern restricts the number of authors to a very small value to search only through a small number of entries.

What is interesting is that this worked great with H2 (much, much faster than the join), but with MySQL it is terribly slow. (This has nothing to do with the LIKE '%pattern%' part, see comments in other answers.) I suppose queries are optimized differently.

Comment: Nice. It'll have been really bad on MySQL btw because MySQL evaluates subqueries every time against the outer query, it doesn't "remember" the results. A known weakness.  Giving it three levels of nesting will hurt a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE name LIKE '%pattern%'` will always take LONG on a 900,000+ row table no matter what you do because when your pattern `'%pattern%'` starts with a `%` MySql can't use any indexes and should do a full table scan. You should look into [full-text indexes and function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Actually, it's not that slow, or at least not for my purpose (see comments in hoppa's answer). Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the like condition starts with a wildcard it will result in a full table scan which is always slow, no internal caching can take place.

If you want to do full text searches, mysql is not the best bet you have. Look into other software ([solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for instance) to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: Two things: 1) I'm primarily using H2. I was using MySQL for comparison only, perhaps I should remove that tag. 2) If I just run SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE name LIKE '%pattern%';, I get a result reasonably fast (half a sec. with H2, a tenth of that with MySQL), and that result has few entries. The real question is how I can get the books associated to these few (author) entries quickly.